# Planar graph proving

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

How to prove weather this graph is planar or not?

[image]

Comment: What are your ideas?

Comment: @Sunyata Well, I tried to draw it as a plane graph but failed, also I used this propertie $m\leq 3n-6$ where m is number of edges and n is number of vertices by that it is planar, not really sure if that is enough to prove it is planar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the original graph

[image]

and the planar embedding:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much